# How do I keep an anchor position after page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and need some help please.  I have a page that draws a random card and I want the card to remain in the same location (#display) after I click, but it keeps repositioning.  I tried to add an eventListener.onclick with preventDefault before this function, but that stops everything from working.

I suspect adding an anchor might work, or maybe a forced reload, but I don't know how. Do I add it in the existing function (and how?) or do I add it in the html? How do I keep the card in the same location after it has been refreshed?

Please help?
Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div class="card-container">
                                        
    <div id="display">
            <h3>Pick a card </h3>
            <img src="assets/cards/background.png" width="400em">
    </div>
    
</div>


<div class="button">
    <button class="yellow-button" id="draw">Draw card</button>
```

Javascript:

```
    var index = getRandom(152);
    var currentCard = deck[index];

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = '<h3>' + currentCard.name + '</h3><img src="assets/cards/' + currentCard.image + '.jpg" width=400em>';
    
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.
Add a class to the `<img>` element and you can set its position in the CSS file.